# how to get rid of "mailto:" in a link

Tags: uri, mailto, canvas-lms

I'm working on LTI, trying to build an app for Instructure Canvas (a learning management system).

I want to insert a link to the lecture content, so I sent a response to Canvas with the link as parameter. Then I got a hyperlinked text. But when I clicked it, I found out the link was prefixed with a "mailto:". How can I get rid of this "mailto:"?

```
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);

            var link =
                @"https://myClass/yinthewater@gmail/Notebooks/math";
            var launch_presentation_return_url = argsDict["launch_presentation_return_url"] + "?return_type=url&url=" + link;
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Uri.UnescapeDataString((launch_presentation_return_url)));

            return response;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the "mailto:" prefix being appended to your URL is due to a bug in Canvas. After testing it against the current master branch on github it looks like it has been fixed in this [github commit](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/commit/57e333ca1db3329eead769a68ac19c7faaa8b945).

For Canvas instance hosted by Instructure they have a 3 week release cycle, where every 3 weeks new code gets deployed to beta, and the current beta gets deployed to production, more details about the release schedule can be found here: [(Canvas release schedule)](https://guides.instructure.com/m/4214/l/199567-when-do-canvas-updates-occur-on-beta-production-and-test-environments)

If you are using a Canvas instance not hosted by Instructure, then it would be up to the host to deploy a newer version of Canvas with the fix.